# What namespace is DbConfiguration in EntityFramework in? Or Why can't I resolve System.Data.Entity.Config?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using Entity Framework 4.4 and would like to try code-based configuration. Following the code example in http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code-based%20Configuration one needs to derive from DbConfiguration.

DbConfiguration seems to be in the namespace System.Data.Entity.Config, but the namespace is not found. I've added all System.Data.* references in the project and still no luck.

What am I missing here?

Comment: OK, apparently EF 4.4 doesn't have System.Data.Entity.Config namespace. Installed EF 6.0 and works.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, that is part of EF6

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx